# Position of dropdown in a QComboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

Is there a way to know the position of the rectangle used by the drop-down of a QComboBox? (the rectangle where the down arrow is displayed)

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you want, but a rectangle of Combobox arrow button can be obtained from the style:

```
QStyle* style = comboBox->style(); 

QStyleOptionComboBox option;
option.rect = comboBox->rect();

QRect r = style->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &option, QStyle::SC_ComboBoxArrow);
```